# Play online Radio Station as a Music on Hold in Asterisk

Tags: streaming, media, asterisk, icecast, internet-radio

Is there a way (**Tool or any idea**) to play radio station (Streamed via **IceCast**) as a **Music On Hold** in **Asterisk**?, I Have a streaming server and Asterisk Server running and working independently very well, **only I want to integrate both of two**.

*Your Help Please, THANKS IN ADVANCE*

My OS: *Linux - Centos*

My Music On Hold Class:

mode=custom

application=/usr/bin/sox mystreamingurl -b 64000 -r 44100 -t ogg -

This script produces upnormal and noisy sound which is totally different from the sound produced by the Streaming Server(IceCas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk's internal sound format is 8khz mono PCM

You should directly specify for sox which output format to use for in and out.

Also sox is NOT streaming utility, you should use something like MPlayer.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-musiconholdconf/#StreamradiousingMPlayerforMOH

```
#!/bin/bash

if -n "`ls /tmp/asterisk-moh-pipe.*`" ; then
rm /tmp/asterisk-moh-pipe.*
fi

PIPE="/tmp/asterisk-moh-pipe.$$"
mknod $PIPE p

mplayer http://address_of_radio_station -really-quiet -quiet -ao pcm:file=$PIPE -af resample=8000,channels=1,format=mulaw 2>/dev/null | cat $PIPE 2>/dev/null
rm $PIPE
```

Comment: Used **MPG123** player and worked like a charm

Udated **MOH Class**:

`mode=custom
application=/usr/bin/mpg123 -q -r 8000 -f 8192 --mono -s http://mystreamingurl`

Answer (score 1):

Used **MPG123** player and worked like a charm

Udated **MOH Class**:

`mode=custom
application=/usr/bin/mpg123 -q -r 8000 -f 8192 --mono -s http://mystreamingurl`